# Save the location of given file

Tags: javascript, html

I wonder if it's possible to choose a file and then save the location to the file to the database, for example `C:\folder\another-folder\file.txt` through HTML or JavaScript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can't do that in browser because of security restrictions. You can get its name (`file.txt'). The only thing you can do - is to give a user an input to select and upload file. After it is on your server - you can do with it whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript and HTML are both evaluated on the client (browser), so without any server-side scripting this is not possible.

Comment: How would server-side scripting get the client file location?

Comment: via a POST or GET request to the server. https://www.google.com/search?q=POST+file+upload

Comment: A file upload gives the file _name_ (and obviously its contents), not its _location_ in the client filesystem. And rightly so.

Comment: i must've misunderstood the exact question. "location to file" is ambiguous if you take into account that a file needs to be stored on the server too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure since I have never actually done something like this in the past -- most likely it is not possible to get the actual location of the file in the native system unless the user inputs it directly, but perhaps you can extract it from a file upload?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp

Comment: Thanks! I did see that the only thing I can get from `input type="file"` is `C:\fakepath\file.txt`. Pitty :/